# Moving text from below the image at the right of it

Tags: html, css

How can I place the text instead of below the image, to the text on image's right?

```
<div class="panel-body">                            
    <img class="img-thumbnail image-text" style="float:left; width:180px;" alt="" src="images/bussniss-pic.jpg">
    <p>
    </p>
</div>
```

css for image

```
.img-thumbnail {
display: inline-block;
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
padding: 4px;
line-height: 1.428571429;
background-color: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #dddddd;
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

[image]

Comment: In what element is the content that's wrapping underneath the `img`? Are you using CSS?

Comment: @BillF. Excuse me, I have updated my question with the css

Answer (score 0):

```
.panel-body p
{
    padding-left: 180px;
}
```

This bumps all of the text in your paragraph over the width of your image. Otherwise, the paragraph is doing what it's supposed to, which is flow around the image.

The image itself is actually overlapping the paragraph, which pushes the text over. It you want the left edge of the text to line up, you have to add enough white-space to account for the image.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nYw6S/

Answer (score 0):

See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4enb7/

HTML

```
<div class="panel-body">                            
    <img class="img-thumbnail image-text" style="width:200px;" alt="" src="images/bussniss-  pic.jpg">
    <div style="display: inline-block">
    <p>
        Text
    </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-thumbnail {
float: left;
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
padding: 4px;
line-height: 1.428571429;
background-color: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #dddddd;
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Using just padding works but if you forget to keep the image and paragraph the same size in both locations, it will be wrong. Also it doesn't accommodate well if images can be multiple sizes.

This example works regardless of the image size. Wrapping the text in a div keeps them all aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your paragraph tag (p) inside a div and float that div left. This way it doesn't matter what size your image is.

```
<div class="panel-body">                            
    <img class="img-thumbnail image-text" style="float:left; width:180px;" alt="" src="images/bussniss-pic.jpg" />
    <div style="float:left;">
        <p>adsf         dsa          fdsa    <br/>     fdsa         fdsa         f        dsaf        asdfadsfdsafdsafdsaf a khndsa jghsa<br/> ufghdsag kusahg usahg uashgoufdsa hgoiusadhgpiusfd hgiudsahgiufdsa<br/> hgiufdsa hgiu hfdspiuga<br/> fdhgiu hfdagpiuafd hgpiufda hgpiufdahg <br/>iufdahg <br/>iufda hg hgjoiafdsjgoiafdsgiufda<br/> giufdah g iufdagoifda <br/>gfda g[odahgf<br/>daiugapkjfhg;akjfdhg ;ajdhg a;jdfhg ;ajhg a;jhg; a;aljsd hg;ajgh<br/> ;agj hafdlkjgh lkjfdahgal<br/> lhfda g
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

See example here http://jsfiddle.net/3fbB3/4/

Comment: I updated your jsFiddle to include a placeholder image, but your solution doesn't seem to work. Might want to work on that

Comment: It does work, but if there is not enough room on the page to fit eveything, the text will move below the image. Updated fiddle with less text.

Comment: You might want to also include a rule for `.panel-body`; floating both children like this means it will collapse to a zero height, which may or may not cause layout issues for elements that follow. A simple `overflow:auto` fixes that.

Comment: True, added a clear:both after. Didn't think about what was going on under